# Whats wrong with this cron?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

If something wrong with this code?
Its not working.
In wp-config I have DISABLE_WP_CRON turn to false.
I have no clue whats wrong. SQL query works fine. It should reset the meta values for all posts once every week and moth. For tests purposes I had given 10 and 30 seconds, but like I'd said - its not working. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance ;)

```
<pre><code>
function os_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['ten_seconds'] = array(
        'interval' => 10, //60 * 60* 24 * 7, // Every week
        'display'  => __( 'Every week' ),
    );
    $schedules['30_seconds'] = array(
        'interval' => 30, //60 * 60* 24 * 30, // Every month
        'display'  => __( 'Every month' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'os_custom_cron_schedule', 10, 1 );

//Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'os_cron_hook_week' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'ten_seconds', 'os_cron_hook_week' );
}
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'os_cron_hook_month' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), '30_seconds', 'os_cron_hook_month' );
}

///Hook into that action that'll fire in given time
add_action( 'os_cron_hook_week', 'week_reset_views' );
add_action( 'os_cron_hook_month', 'month_reset_views' );

//create your function, that runs on cron
function week_reset_views() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta SET meta_value = 0 WHERE meta_key = 'post_views_weekly'");
}
function month_reset_views() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta SET meta_value = 0 WHERE meta_key = 'post_views_monthly'");
}
</pre></code>
```

Comment: "its not working" isn't a helpful problem statement.  What _is_ happening?  What debugging have you already done?  Help us help you.

Comment: This is not a standard CRON. You should add how this CRON is being used/fired. `If something wrong with this code?` is almost impossible for us to answer. You need to define the problem you need help with.

Comment: I dont have acces to logs, so cant log errors there. I fired this sql in page template and it worked so this is OK. Function week_reset_views should fire for example once every ten second, but nothing happens. It is WP CRON